# Unity iOS - URL Scheme launch both application and app store

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, url-scheme

I'm using a URL scheme to test an open application. The device opens the app and opens the additional app store afterward.

I tried to set the Unity version to the same version in app store but it still happens.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

All answers are appreciated! Thank you!